# CCA security in QROM for symmetric schemes

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, chosen-ciphertext-attack

Assume that we have a symmetric encryption scheme $\Pi_s$ that is IND-CCA secure in the standard model. Does this imply that $\Pi_s$ is IND-CCA in QROM?

Comment: I think the IND-CCA of $\Pi_s$ in the standard model implicitly says that the implementation of $\Pi_s$ does not use the random oracle (or at least independent to security proof), and thus IND-CCA in QROM as well (because the security of the scheme is independent to RO). Could you clarify the application in your mind?